# PHP add key => value to each array in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

Best shown in practice, I have 2-dimensional array like this:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(4) "3229"
        ["name"]=> string(0) "foo"
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(4) "2588"
        ["name"]=> string(4) "1800"
    }
    [2]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(4) "3234"
        ["name"]=> string(4) "8100"
    }
}
```

And i want to add a `["type"]=> string(0) "type1"` to each array so i would get this

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(4) "3229"
        ["name"]=> string(0) "foo"
        ["type"]=> string(0) "type1"
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(4) "2588"
        ["name"]=> string(4) "1800"
        ["type"]=> string(0) "type1"
    }
    [2]=> array(2) {
        ["id"]=> string(4) "3234"
        ["name"]=> string(4) "8100"
        ["type"]=> string(0) "type1"
    }
}
```

I know there is a pretty simple way how to do this with `foreach` and `array_push()` but is there some simple one-liner for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as &$val) $val['type'] = 'type1';
```

I think it's fastest way

Comment: Just did the same thing, SO made me lazy :)

Comment: Please don't forget to `unset($val)` after this code.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key){$value['type'] = 'type1';})
```

would also work in php 5.3+

Comment: yes, but in this case, it will take a bit more time than foreach with reference

Comment: I agree, but you beat me to the foreach answer, So I posted an alternative